# Interesting behavior in sequential code execution

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

**EDIT 2: I'm still stuck here, but the problem is most likely located in the auto-vectorization rewriting system, which is irrelevant to this question. I'm updating this question again on valgrind's SIGILL output mentioned in the comments below**

```
==10478== Process terminating with default action of signal 4 (SIGILL) 
==10478== Illegal opcode at address 0x423F4C ==10478== at 0x423F4C: sp_private_9_compute (smmintrin.h:209) 
==10478== by 0x4247F4: sp_private_9__timeCompute
```

**The FIRST thing to check if you see SIGILL raised by valgrind when debugging SSE code is that YOUR VALGRIND IS UP-TO-DATE** In my case, I was using V3.6 which had bugs in SSE4 intrinsic support. SIGILL was raised b/c it didn't understand the _mm_mullo_epi32 instruction. After updating it to V3.9, valgrind can better locate the real problem of the SSE program.

I'll update this question again if I find more relevant debugging tips.

---

**EDIT 1: I hope someone can confirm my observation of the non-sequential behavior in the debugging trace is accurate.**

---

First of all, this is a very specific question about C debugging. I really appreciate if you read it through and provide any feedback.

**Background**: I'm working with a code generation system, and I recently keep getting a "double free or corruption" from glibc. So I recompiled the auto-generated code with extra debugging information and ran it with **gdb**. And either I'm brain-dead right now, or I actually observed **a non-sequential behavior in sequential code execution**.

**Codes**:

```
LINE:6851     if(self->_garbage != 0) {
LINE:6852            sp_env_list_free_children(self->_garbage);
LINE:6853            sp_env_list___del__(self->_garbage);
LINE:6854            sp_env_free(self->_garbage, sizeof(sp_env_list_t));
LINE:6855     }//End of if
LINE:6856   }//End of an outer if structure
LINE:6857 }//End of the function call containing the if structure
```

I'll explain the free and del funcs after the debugging trace.

**Debugging Trace**

```
6851   if (((self->_garbage != 0))) {
(gdb) step
6852   sp_env_list_free_children(self->_garbage);
(gdb) print self->_garbage 
$1 = (sp_env_list_t *) 0x649080
(gdb) step
6853   sp_env_list___del__(self->_garbage); 
(gdb) print self->_garbage 
$2 = (sp_env_list_t *) 0x649080
(gdb) step
6854      sp_env_free(self->_garbage, sizeof(sp_env_list_t )); 
(gdb) print self->_garbage 
$3 = (sp_env_list_t *) 0x649080
(gdb) step
6857   }
(gdb) print self->_garbage 
$4 = (sp_env_list_t *) 0x649080
(gdb) step
sp_private_11___del__ (self=<value optimized out>) at sp_moddft_int32.c:6854
6854      sp_env_free(self->_garbage, sizeof(sp_env_list_t )); 
(gdb) print self->_garbage 
Cannot access memory at address 0x18
(gdb) step
Single stepping until exit from function sp_env_free, 
which has no line number information.
*__GI___libc_free (mem=0x649080) at malloc.c:3692
3692    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
    in malloc.c
```

As you can see in the debugging trace, it reaches to Line 6857 after Line 6854, and then comes back to Line 6854 again. Since self->_garbage has been freed completely, this should be where the "**double free or corruption**" happens. However, the entire function is sequential with no loops. I don't understand why it jumped back.

For the completeness of the question, the three functions in the if structure are for:

- sp_env_list_free_children() frees all e->_data from e = self->_garbage->head to e = self->_garbage->tail.
- sp_env_list_**del**() deletes pointers from self->_garbage->head to self->_garbage->tail
- sp_env_free() frees self->_garbage pointer

I can provide any additional information if it's not clear. I hope someone can at least confirm my observation of the non-sequential behavior is accurate. Thanks so much!

Comment: try valgrind; it will show where data has been freed

Comment: @ensc Thank you. I've been using valgrind mostly for memleak check. I did run the program with valgrind as: valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full ./sp_bench_moddft_int32 327 64 --cpu-frequency 3184. I also set MALLOC_CHECK_=2 if that matters. I don't quite see where the data has been freed (it's a 21K LoC auto-generated C program, so there's a lot of information from Valgrind). Should I use different flags for valgrind to see where the free happens?

Comment: "a lot of information from valgrind" indicate usually a lot of problems ;)   Double free() errors are usually reported as `Address ... is 0 bytes inside a block of size ... free'd` and next lines are telling location of the first free()

Comment: You can drop the --leak-check=full, as you're not debugging memory leaks. There should not be a lot of information from valgrind - if there is, it's probably from errors in the code, and you have to fix those. Start with the first error. Also to be sure, is the code you're debugging compiled without any optimization ?

Comment: @ensc Right on. Currently, I consider reasonable memory leak acceptable. I'll be working on improving that after the current problem is fixed. Valgrind reported SIGILL, which is the result of double free. Here's the detailed msg from valgrind (I wish I could edit code in comments): 

`==10478== Process terminating with default action of signal 4 (SIGILL)
==10478==  Illegal opcode at address 0x423F4C
==10478==    at 0x423F4C: sp_private_9_compute (smmintrin.h:209)
==10478==    by 0x4247F4: sp_private_9__timeCompute (sp_moddft_int32.c:6269)
==10478==    by 0x438F93: sp_timeable_env_time...`

Comment: @nos The code is compiled with -O3 and -msse4.2 by gcc. -msse4.2 is the flag for SSE 4.2 ISA by Intel.

Comment: @K.G. That atleast explains why your gdb jumps around like that. It's normally hard to impossible to single step optimized code and make sense of what's going on. Also drop the -msse4.2 flag, it might be valgrind doesn't quite understand the code generated in that case.

Comment: @nos I'll drop the -O3 and recompile. The -msse4.2 flag has to be there though, since the code (21K LoC) is auto generated and vectorized and has to use instructions from SSE 4.2. I'll update later. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Optimized code often appears to jump around randomly when you single-step through it. The optimizer is free to reorganize code flow as long as the defined ordering relations are maintained.

In this case, I suspect you're seeing the result of tail call optimization (TCO). Your final call to `sp_env_free` is a tail-call, assuming that the function it is in has `void` return. Consequently, it is possible for the function to restore its callee-save registers (that is, execute the epilogue), and then jump to `sp_env_free`, rather than calling `sp_env_free` and then executing the epilogue. That saves a stack frame and a few instructions to set the stack frame up.

Since the epilogue is at the end of the function, it nominally has line number 6857, even though all that is visible on that line is a close brace. So TCO is completely consistent with the sequence of line numbers you see. I'm sure it's not the only possibility, though. In general, it's not easy to second guess a good optimizer; if you really want to know, you could try looking at the generated assembler code with `-S`, but given that your file has at least 6857 lines, that might not be easy to decipher either.

If you want to sensibly debug the program, turn optimization off.

Comment: That's a very interesting point. I remember learning Tail Recursion Elimination in class, but this may be the first time I see TCO in real action. My question is, with or without TCO, the `sp_env_free` should be executed just once. But `sp_en_free`(Line 6854) showed up twice as `step` is called in gdb, does it mean the first appearance is skipped? Also, right before the second call, it says `sp_private_11___del__ (self=<value optimized out>) at sp_moddft_int32.c:6854`, does it mean self is optimized to be a NULL pointer (which leads to the error)?

Comment: @K.G.: Line 6854 shows up twice as the next line to execute, but that doesn't mean that *all* of line 6854 is executed twice. It means that part of line 6854 was executed, then (at least part of) line 6857, and then the rest of line 6854. `value optimized out` means that the value is not present anywhere that gdb can find it. In this case, it's probably because self->garbage_ has been looked up and stored in a register, and self is no longer needed, so it's nowhere to be found (it probably was on the now-dismantled stack frame). None of this is relevant to your bug.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! I read the TCO again just now. It's supposed to keep the function arguments and local variables from the calling frame (now modified for and used by the tail call). Assume self->_garbage is now stored in a register, the first arg to the second call to `sp_env_free` should be pointing at that same register. Then as you can see, all previous `print self->_garbage` returns a valid address in the calling stack frame, but leads to the bug at the second call to `sp_en_free`. I don't quite understand how the address of the self->_garbage pointer is lost here.

Comment: @K.G.: I honestly think you'll find the bug is elsewhere. You probably accidentally free'd the memory region previously, possibly by aliasing. Try recompiling without optimization and you'll find it easier to follow the logic, but remember that if the bug is that the first `free` had the wrong address, *it has already happened*.

Comment: This may help, the definition of sp_env_free(): `void  sp_env_free(void *ptr, size_t size) {
    SP_env_alloc -= size;
    free(ptr);
}`

Comment: @K.G.: Last try. *There is nothing wrong with `sp_env_free`*. The problem happened earlier; it was *detected* when `sp_env_free` was called. Also notice in your debug session that the libc `free` is called with *the correct argument*: `__GI___libc_free (mem=0x649080)`. You do yourself no favour by assuming that your bug is the result of a bug in the tools you are using (C compiler, standard library, etc.) There are such bugs but they are extremely rare, and *this is not one of them*.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I was not assuming the gcc or glibc were buggy. I was trying to understand the debugging trace, especially the TCO part before you pointed that out. I'll dump the freed addresses to see where the problem actually happens. Thanks again!